# Writing Interpreter for standalone c++ applications / Modules

Tags: c++, interpreter

1. I have 3 standalone c++ componenets i.e Driver , Parser and Translater
2. Driver connects to data source and fetches data , parser parses data and Transform converts the data as needed i.e the flow of data looks like below

   ```
   Driver.Out --> Parser.In -- Parser.Out --> Translator.In
   ```
3. I want to write a runtime interpreter which ties these components with Queues and produce the desired output.
4. I wanna use this interpreter as many times as possible , each being a independent Process

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated

Comment: You've given a exceedingly vague description of your situation, no requirements to speak of, no idea of your  operating environment, and *no idea where you are stuck*. What do you expect us to do?

Comment: Ok just help me out how two c++ modules comminicate using queues

Comment: Nobody can help you, because your questions are too vague, ill formulated, and you don't show any code. Your terminology is non standard (modules or components don't mean much in C++ context).

Comment: Please edit your question and reformulate it carefully. Check that your terminology is appropriate (i.e. on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki ...). What are the queues you are speaking about? what is the driver? What is the parser? Show us the code you actually have written!)

Comment: Ok lets talk about only parser and trnslator (2 c++ exe) my idea is to get trans input from parser with queue data sy

Comment: Show your code please!!! We can't help you otherwise!! Your questions are too badly formulated and nobody understands them!!! For instance queues in C++ context refers to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/ and we don't understand what you mean.

Comment: As long as you stay vague -without showing your code- and don't improve a lot your communication skills & your terminology nobody can help you

Comment: Ok i going to bed i will talk to yu tomorrow

Comment: I am rephrasing the question. I want to implement message queues in interpreter ( may be through a interpreter api ) so that parser and translator have their own input and out queues and translator is a consumer for parser

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider embedding an interpreter like [lua](http://www.lua.org/) inside your application, or embed your application as an extension for [ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html) or [python](http://python.org/)

But I don't understand exactly your question.

Comment: What i mean is i have already coded parser.cpp and transform.cpp and created relevant exe s

Comment: I still don't understand your question. If you have a working parser, you should be happy. And we don't understand your overall goal. You really should take time to explain much better your problem and its overall context (that is, your goal). Explaining well enough your question is part of solving it!

Comment: What i want is to create a runtime env for these modules by tying relevant inputs and outputs to achieve desired result

Comment: Could you define more what you call a runtime environment (is it related to garbage collection???)? And what you call tying inputs to outputs? And what you want as the desired result?? You really ask very badly your question. Try to write it first on pencil & paper, and show it to someone not understanding your work...

Comment: Perhaps publishing all your software (with an appropriate opensource license) on some free repository like gitorious.org could help you (and us). Nobody understands what you want to achieve and what you are asking!!!

Comment: Welcome yur patience let me be real simple i want the translator to consume parsers output what translater does is simply change parsers output as per translator rules

Comment: I don't understand anything in your last comment

Comment: Ok can yu put out some code on two c++ modules communicating using queues

Comment: Ok basil i justhave two exe written by my college my job is to integrate them and get the output i have put out my idea in earlier comment pls validate

Answer (score 0):

Use [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) and [bison](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/). A good book on how to write interpreters or compilers with them is [Flex & Bison: Text Processing Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596155972) by John Levine.

Comment: Another possibility is http://antlr.org/ however, I am not at all sure the original poster's question (which we don't understand) is about parsing.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Agreed. I just tried to help the OP modify the post and ask the right question :)